# VBA vlookup iferror formula error '1004' while inserting a formula to cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a short code about inserting a formula to the cell instead of obtaining values but when I tried to use that with VLOOKUP and/or IFERROR, I get error 1004. I did it with SUB, SUBTOTAL before but couldn't achieved with these functions. If you may help, that would be amazing.

```
GerçekStok = 0

Set StokBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set BticinoBook = Workbooks("BTICINO.xlsm")

NoS = BticinoBook.Sheets.Count

For k = 1 To NoS
        If BticinoBook.Sheets(k).Name = "DRAFT" Then
                DNumber = k
                Exit For
        End If
Next k
TotalRow = BticinoBook.Sheets(DNumber).Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row



If GerçekStok = 0 Then
        For i = 2 To TotalRow
                BticinoBook.Sheets(DNumber).Cells(i, 2) = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D" & i & ";'[" & StokBook.Name & "]Sheet2'!$A:$E;3;FALSE);" & Chr(34) & Chr(48) & Chr(34) & Chr(41)

        Next i
Else
        For i = 2 TotalRow
                BticinoBook.Sheets(DNumber).Cells(i, 2) = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D" & i & ";'[" & StokBook.Name & "]Sheet2'!$A:$E;4;FALSE);" & Chr(34) & Chr(48) & Chr(34) & Chr(41)
        Next i
End If
```

Comment: why are you using `& Chr(34) & Chr(48) & Chr(34) & Chr(41)` instead of typing the characters???

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.Formula` to enter a formula into a cell.

```
Range("B10").Formula = "=SUM(B4:B9)"
```

If your string contains another string with double quotes, then you need to type the double quote twice, like this:

```
   ... whatever... ;FALSE);""0"")"
```

Using Chr() instead of the typed characters doesn't really fix the issue.

```
BticinoBook.Sheets(DNumber).Cells(i, 2).formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D" & i & ";'[" & StokBook.Name & "]Sheet2'!$A:$E;3;FALSE);""0"")"
```

Of course, there is no reason to put a zero inside of double quotes, so you could simply use

```
BticinoBook.Sheets(DNumber).Cells(i, 2).formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D" & i & ";'[" & StokBook.Name & "]Sheet2'!$A:$E;3;FALSE);0)"
```